# Compact expression to bash if statement

Tags: bash

How can I make a more compact expression to this ?

```
if [[ $arg =~ ^[[:digit:]]+$ ]]; then 
  vb=$arg
else
  vb=1
fi
```

Comment: `vb=1; [[ $arg =~ ^[[:digit:]]+$ ]] && vb=$arg`. But I'm not sure why: the if statement is at least clear in what it does

Comment: Shall keep things clear then.  Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your statement assigns `$arg` to the variable `vb` if `$arg` contains only digits, otherwise it assigns `1` to `vb`.

As such, it is fairly compact and it's clear what is happening, assuming that the reader knows how to interpret extended regular expressions.

Another way to formulate it would be to use

```bsh
vb=1
[[ $arg =~ ^[[:digit:]]+$ ]] && vb=$arg
```

as suggested in comments, but this costs you in readability.

Another way to formulate the code would be to delegate the test to a function:

```bsh
is_whole_number () {
    [[ $1 =~ ^[[:digit:]]+$ ]]
}

if is_whole_number "$arg"; then
    vb=$arg
else
    vb=1
fi
```

This is more code, but the actual `if`-statement is shorter and at the same time easier to understand, even for a person not well versed in regular expressions or shell scripting.

Comment: Have not seen a function used in this way, as a condition.  I quite like it and will use it. I could also have another function for real numbers as so `^[+-]?[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?$`.